# R leaflet Rstudio shows empty map using addProviderTiles Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio

I have been trying to add layers from a statistical source using the addProviderTiles function. 
The data comes from this source: http://www.cbs.nl/nl-NL/menu/themas/dossiers/nederland-regionaal/publicaties/geografische-data/archief/2015/wijk-en-buurtkaart-2014-art.htm

My code is the following:

```
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)

wijken2 <- readOGR("C://", layer="buurt_2014", verbose=FALSE)
newijken <- subset(wijken2, wijken2$GM_NAAM %in% c("Amsterdam"))
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "Blues",domain = newijken$AUTO_TOT)

leaflet(newijken) %>% addPolygons(stroke= FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5, color= ~pal(AUTO_TOT)) %>% addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")
```

The result is the basic empty CartoDB map.

I've tried a similar approach using the data from https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shapes.html. This does show the added layers.

Is there something I have to change in the data?

Thanks!

Comment: without data it's hard to reproduce your problem. Can you include your dataset?

Comment: See the link: http://www.cbs.nl/nl-NL/menu/themas/dossiers/nederland-regionaal/publicaties/geografische-data/archief/2015/wijk-en-buurtkaart-2014-art.htm . The website is in Dutch, but the data can be found under the Wijk- en Buurtkaart 2014 (67Mb) link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your projection was wrong. In longlat it seems to work and it looks it's in the right country :) Is this want you want?

so run

```
newijken_latlng <- spTransform(newijken, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
leaflet() %>%
  addPolygons(data = newijken_latlng, color= ~pal(AUTO_TOT)) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")
```

[image]